# How to make input text as untouch by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to remove red border after making empty input-box,

How can I make this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="123" required="required">
<input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="$('#test').val('');">
```

Comment: not getting what you are ttying to achieve

Comment: I want to remove red border, but as a untouched text field. please run my code snippet and click on button.

Comment: but i cant see ant red border here

Comment: may be you are using chrome , can you please check it in firefox ?

Comment: ok so remove required attribute in inputbox, to remove red border

Comment: sorry I can't , My button is as 'reset' button and I want that field as required and remove that red border.

Comment: I have added my answer..check it will solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css:

Check in firefox, you will get result;

```
:not(output):-moz-ui-invalid {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```css
:not(output):-moz-ui-invalid {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="123" required="required">
<input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="$('#test').val('');">
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to apply some css

```html
<style>
    input:required {
    box-shadow:none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="123" required="required">
<input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="$('#test').val('');">
```

Comment: I found the way by you answer